# systemd /dev/xx access changed when restart systemd

Tags: systemd

When I restart systemd in docker container A, `/dev/XXX`'s access will be changed. For example:

before:

```
docker exec -it xxxx bash 
chmod 755 /dev/random
```

do:

```
docker restart xxxx
```

after:

```
docker exec -it xxxx bash
```

`/dev/random` will be changed to `0666`

where position systemd modify this in systemd source code? Is this logically?

Is this relate to systemd-udevd?

```
Execute /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd? [Yes, No, Skip] [**    ] (4 of 6) A start job is running for Create Volatile Files and Directories (3min 48s / no limit)y
[***   ] (5 of 6) A start job is running for Mark the need to relabel after reboot (3min 49s / no limit)(src/core/manager.c:1519) Got notification message for unit -.slice
(src/core/manager.c:1519) Got notification message for unit systemd-udevd.service
(src/core/service.c:2741) systemd-udevd.service: Got notification message from PID 503 (READY=1)
(src/core/service.c:2785) systemd-udevd.service: got READY=1
(src/core/service.c:878) systemd-udevd.service changed start -> running
(src/core/job.c:811) Job systemd-udevd.service/start finished, result=done
[  OK  ] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
```

Answer (score 2):

`/dev` is not a "real" filesystem, it is a `devtmpfs`, i.e. a `tmpfs` or ramdisk, with the sole purpose of holding the device nodes created at boot time by `udev`.

You can see this if you use `df`'s `-T` option:

```
# df -T /dev
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs    498256     0    498256   0% /dev
```

Because it is a ramdisk, the contents do not survive a reboot.  This is intentional, and not a problem - `udev` will create the device nodes needed by the system at boot time.

If you want `/dev/random` to have specific non-standard permissions after reboot, you'd need to create a rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` that set the permissions you want.  It's hard to see why you'd want `755` for `/dev/random`, though.

Comment: thanks you so much , `/dev/random` is just a example

Comment: when I use bellow configure in docker,  and I restart this container , but , I see  /dev/random is also 0666 but not 0777, that's why

#cat /etc/udev/udev.conf
KERNEL=="random",  GROUP="root", MODE="0777", OPTIONS="last_rule"

Comment: you add udev rules in a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` (files in there are applied in order, sorted by filename), not in `/etc/udev/udev.conf`.